# Sorting of two-dimensional Array not working

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this array, I want to sort it `ticketid` wise, which is a number. Below is the code I am trying

```
    console.log(this.tableData);
    var filtered_tableData = this.tableData.sort((a, b)=> a.ticketid- b.ticketid)
    console.log(filtered_tableData);
```

But it is not sorting as expected.

Here is my array:

[image]

### Edit 1

After trying this code, my result array still remains the same

```
    console.log(this.tableData);
    var filtered_tableData = this.tableData.sort((a,b) => (a.ticketid > b.ticketid) ? 1 : ((b.ticketid > a.ticketid) ? -1 : 0)); 
    console.log(filtered_tableData);
```

Please note `this.tableData` and `filtered_tableData` result is same in console.log.

See image below

[image]

Comment: It's not a 2-d array, btw - it's an array of objects.

Answer (score 2):

Change the sort callback to specify a descending order, and you don't need a new reference variable (filtered_tableData) because the sort acts on the original reference tableData

```js
const tableData = [{ ticketid: 24}, { ticketid: 12 }, { ticketid: 90 }]
tableData.sort((a, b) => a.ticketid > b.ticketid ? -1 : 1)
console.log(tableData)
```

Comment: what's the difference `a.ticketid > b.ticketid ? -1 : 1` and `b.ticketid - a.ticketid`?

Comment: @NikitaMadeev you can do that as well but you need to change the compare function accordingly https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description

Comment: your answer is not working with my array of objects, do we need to do something else ?

Comment: what is not working exactly? if you check the code snippet above with a generic array of objects which is a subset of yours, it works fine, post the new output

Comment: New output is same

Comment: Doesnt work, i have updated my question, see edit :: 1

Answer (score 1):

descending sort should be b.ticketid - a.ticketid:

```
let ar = [{ticketid:3},{ticketid:5},{ticketid:2}]
    var filtered_tableData = ar.sort((a, b)=> b.ticketid - a.ticketid)
    console.log(filtered_tableData);
```

Comment: Doesnt work, i have updated my question, see edit :: 1

Comment: maybe parent object change definition of sort method, try to clone the array and sort them:
let nar = tableData.map(i => i).sort((a, b)=> b.ticketid - a.ticketid)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried variations of:

```
sort((a, b)=> b.ticketid - a.ticketid)
sort((b, a)=> b.ticketid - a.ticketid)
sort((b, a)=> a.ticketid - b.ticketid)
```

My background is C# so it's just a shot in the dark but thought it might help.